# Cannot navigate through input line and history of input lines of the program Miranda

Tags: command-line

I have a program, only the binary (edit: the [source](http://miranda.org.uk/downloads) is available as well, but the problem remains): the propriety functional programming language interpreter [Miranda](http://miranda.org.uk/). It is activated in a terminal from the command line and then repeatedly reads an input line from the command line and writes the output to the terminal. Unfortunately, I cannot move freely back and forth (using arrow keys or otherwise) on the input line to edit the new input line, neither can I navigate through the history of previous input lines. Only the backspace key works as expected. When I use arrows keys, page up/down keys, or Control+key combinations, their code is displayed rather than that their intended effect is established. **My question is: what can I do so that (during interaction with Miranda) I can navigate with arrow keys through the input line, and through the history of previous inputs?**

Currently I use Gnome-terminal, bash, Ubuntu 16.4, but the problem was present in all previous versions of my system and also in proper Unix - since 1986.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a little late for the response, but here it is.

1. Install `rlwrap`: `$ sudo apt install rlwrap -y`
2. Create a `mira` function inside your `~/.bashrc` or default shell equivalent that's wrapped into `rlwrap`:

```
function mira() {
  rlwrap mira $1
}
```

3. Restart your terminal or run `$ source ~/.bashrc`.

This should be enough to enable the navigation correctly.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, 'apt install rlwrap -y' gives the following output: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Nest I tried: 'sudo apt install rlwrap -y'  and this gives: Reading package lists... Done
Segmentation faulty tree... 0%

Comment: You have to execute it as, `sudo`. I forgot to mention that. I updated  my answer.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks!!! (I wish I would have known this solution thirty years ago!! But better late than never. Thanks, again.)